# Using BASH how can I capture the last 5 lines of a log file without causing file locking

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that is created by an application. The app is perpetually writing large volumes of data to the file.
I need to capture a copy of the last 10 lines of the file periodically and write it to another file without causing any file locking, which could impact the application writing the logFile.

How do I do that without impacting the application writing the logfile? i.e without causing any file locking.

logFile example

```
1452431219885,546,Item Details Request,200,OK,text,true,12562,91,91,271,ip-172-31-36-138,0,134
1452431219886,1300,Select Item Request,200,OK,text,true,28541,91,91,444,ip-172-31-36-138,0,209
1452431219889,210,Login Success Page Request,200,OK,text,true,29405,91,91,123,ip-172-31-36-137,0,27
1452431219898,217,Item Details Request,200,OK,text,true,10620,91,91,215,ip-172-31-36-135,0,106
1452431219900,1668,Logout and Exit Request,200,OK,text,true,19676,92,92,1133,ip-172-31-36-136,0,266
1452431219902,589,Search Page Request,200,OK,text,true,13392,91,91,296,ip-172-31-36-138,0,147
1452431219903,589,Save Basket Request,200,OK,text,true,17473,91,91,294,ip-172-31-36-138,0,147
1452431219908,1135,Search Results Request,200,OK,text,true,561615,91,91,229,ip-172-31-36-136,0,116
1452431219914,1114,Item Details Request,200,OK,text,true,93243,91,91,282,ip-172-31-36-138,0,138
1452431219921,825,Select Item Request,200,OK,text,true,24354,91,91,339,ip-172-31-36-135,0,161
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you used the `awk` and `sed` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Obtain the last 10 lines**

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use:

```
# tail reads the input file and print out the last 10 lines (default)
tail /path/to/file.log > 10_lines.dump
# Change number of lines from default(10) to 5
tail -n 5 /path/to/file.log > 5_lines.dump
```

**Show last lines every X seconds**

If you need to do this periodically without saving the output you can use `watch`:

```
# watch show the output of the tail command every 5 seconds (default 2s)
watch -n 5 tail /path/to/file.log
# OR last 5 lines every 5 seconds
watch -n 5 tail -n 5 /path/to/file.log
```

**Extract and save for future reference in background**

Create a `crontab` file (name it `file.crontab` or as you wish) with an editor of your choice with this content:

```
# ** Crontab file schema **
# .------------------ [m]inute:           [0 - 59] OR */x (every x minutes) 
# |   .-------------- [h]our:             [0 - 23] OR */x (every x hours) 
# |   |   .---------- [d]ay [o]f [m]onth: [1 - 31]
# |   |   |   .------ [mon]th:            [1 - 12] OR jan,feb,mar,apr... 
# |   |   |   |   .-- [d]ay [o]f [w]eek:  [0 - 6]  (Sunday can be 0 or 7)
# |   |   |   |   |                       (also: sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat)
# m   h   d  mon dow
# *   *   *   *   *   command executed every minute with my user permission
# --
# Execute tail every 5 minutes and append last 10 lines of input to log.extract
*/5   *   *   *   *   tail "/path/to/file.log" >> "/path/to/log.extract"
```

Install it on your system using `crontab`:

```
crontab file.crontab
```

Comment: Does tail cause any file locking. i.e If the application writing the file wants to write at the same time I use tail would that cause any file contention issues?

Comment: ITYM No, `tail` doesn't lock the file. One problem you will have though is that if you execute tail while your other command is writing to the file you will find that tail can output the partial line (with no ending newline) that your other command is in the middle of writing. Just something for you to consider and decided if that's desirable or not for your needs.

Comment: @user1654528: I re-read my previous comment and since can be misunderstood i rewrote it here: absolutely there there are any problems of locking (so that ``tail -f log`` is the default way to live monitor a log file). Obviously because the two flows are not synchronized (log output of the process and input of ``tail``)  as Ed Morton remarks: the last line may be incomplete.

Comment: @GiuseppeRicupero thanks for your detailed responses.-very helpful. I wanted to qualify your last comment though. 'absolutely there there are any problems of locking' can you confirm what you mean here please?

Comment: @user1654528: as stated below by user3035772 the files can't be locked in any way. The only problem that may occur it's of sync type: your one-shot tail command may capture an half written line at the bottom (since your program and the tail tool is not synchronized).

Answer (score 4):

Under most operating systems (i.e. BSDs, Linux, Mac, essentially anything not Windows), files never get locked unless the program explicitly requests it.
Even then, locks in these operating systems are only advisory, so won't affect programs which don't care about them.

So the answer is: almost anything that can get the last lines of the log, will do so without locking.

Comment: Thanks to point out this, some programs as ``vim`` use an hidden support file to **lock** r/w operations on the file they currently are operate on. But it's only a custom mechanism that alerts other instances of itself if they try to modify the same file at the same time. Another editor such as ``nano`` ignore this *locks* at all.